# how do I edit wavefront.obj file using c++

Tags: visual-c++, 3d, maya, 3dsmax, meshlab

I would like to edit a .obj file using c++ or any programming language which can be used with a 3d software (a 3d object with a scripting language).

Any suggestions that could be of help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OBJ is a simple text format, just positions of vertiles in plain ASCII... You can edit it in notepad.
There are ready parsing modules for C++, Python, etc.

The simplest way would be to use Python API for Your choosen software, both Maya and 3ds Max has one.. But You've got to tell something more on what is Your goal